# react router navigation image with text link not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a simple vertical nav panel which nav sections consist of image to the left and some text to the right. It looks like the following:

[image: nav stack]

The code of the nav section is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import data from '../../data/data.json'


export default class TopBarMenuItems extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const MENUITEMS = data.menuData.map((item) => { //pls note use of loop here
        let srcPath = require(`../../image/topBarMenuIcons/${item.src}`);
        return (
            <div className="menuItem" dataset={item.id}>
                <a href={item.url} className="topbarLink">
                    <div>
                        <img src={srcPath} />
                    </div>
                    {item.name}
                </a>

            </div>
        )
    });

    return MENUITEMS;
  }
};
```

The problem is that when I click on the text (some link 1) I get redirected to the desired page, but when I click on the image, I dont. So the ideas is to get redirected to the same page when either image or text is clicked. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you put the code in a sandbox so we can play around with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-router-dom library

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import data from '../../data/data.json'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom' 

export default class TopBarMenuItems extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const MENUITEMS = data.menuData.map((item) => {
        let srcPath = require(`../../image/topBarMenuIcons/${item.src}`);
        return (
            <div className="menuItem" dataset={item.id}>
                <Link to={item.url} className="topbarLink">
                    <div>
                        <img src={srcPath} />
                    </div>
                    {item.name}
                </Link>

            </div>
        )
    });

    return MENUITEMS;
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you for reply. cannot start the code this way, it is saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of null`

Comment: my bad, you have to wrap your main component into BrowserRouter and set routes like shown here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start
first example

Comment: And also non react thing, div is not needed inside Link component. Just img or span if you realy need something to wrap

Comment: span does not let `a` link work, I have already removed div. As for BrowserRouter, it is said in the training that I need to provide something like `component={Index}` there. But what should I do if I get the data for my link from the array and I dont know which component is going to be there. THe only thing I know is path...

Comment: so, i've simulated your case without Link component and it's working, you can see on my codepen sandbox https://codepen.io/KoldunMax/pen/KjLPWz